# Directshow dvd filter Graph

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net, dvd

Is there anyone that can help me, with an example on how to build a dvd filter Graph with menus in `Pure C#`.

I can only find `C++` examples and they are no good to me..

[C++ Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318241(v=vs.85).aspx/)

This is a code snippet I got from the `DirectShow.net Samples`

```
var ivideowindow = typeof(IVideoWindow).GUID;
hr = dvdGraph.GetDvdInterface(ivideowindow, out comobj );
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
```

`hr = -2147467262` - `hr may only be 1 or 0`

Exception message is `No such interface supported`

But without that Interface It's nearly impossible to render the actual video..

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at `\Samples\Players\DvdPlay` sample in [DirectShow.NET Samples](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/). It is a port of DVD playback code you are basically referring to.

Comment: I am afraid it's the best you can get. Perhaps you could also find something at CodeProject, CodePlex and similar sites.

Comment: I might figure it out eventually, I just asked to see if someone knew how to avoid this problem..